# Motorcycle no crank, no start TVS RR310 (BMW G310)

Tags: motorcycle, starting, no-crank-no-start

Motorcycle was in running state, then at the end of the day, I got a low battery signal. The motorcycle wouldn't start, I tried recharging the battery and it started running fine but got the low battery signal again, then I was not able to start the motorcycle.

The battery is two years old and it has expired. I installed a new battery and now the battery is fine. Horn, turn signals and headlight works.

Never had this issue but now when I turn the key, fuel injector primes but now I got no crank and no start.

I'm able to start the motorcycle by pushing it to some speed and getting into gear suddenly.

Thank you.

Edit: Checked fuse box and there were no blown fuses.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! A couple of things: 1) you sure it's in neutral when you are trying to start it? 2) Is the kickstand all the way up? I know some bikes have a switch to prevent it from starting when down. I realize my questions are rudimentary, but they are pertinent.

Comment: Hi @Paulster2, thank you, yes it is in neutral, tried without the kickstand.

Comment: Took it to a mechanic, the alternator was blown, I still don't know why it did not start. It's all fixed now.

Comment: Please put that down as the answer so the question will close out. I'm glad you were able to get it fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I took it to a mechanic and he diagnosed that the alternator was blown. It started working normally after replacing the alternator.